# LinearLayout WeightSum not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MasterLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="4000">
<View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="200"
android:visibility="invisible" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/Name"
android:text="James Madison"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textColor="#4b8dcf"
android:textSize="24dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="300"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="#00000000" />
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/Image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1000"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/pro1" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/Title"
android:text="Lead Civil Engineer"
android:textColor="#4b8dcf"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textSize="16dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="150"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="#00000000" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/Company"
android:text="Telco Corp"
android:textColor="#4b8dcf"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textSize="16dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="175"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="#00000000" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/Pitch"
android:text="Engineer specializing in bridge construction and maintenance. Looking for mechanical engineers and designers to work on an exciting new project."
android:textColor="#A7A9AB"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="16dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1000"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="#00000000" />
<View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="100"
android:visibility="invisible" />
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/TagMasterLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="500">

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/TagLayout"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/user"
android:layout_width="25dp"
android:layout_height="25dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/profile" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/GreenTagMasterLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="500">
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/GreenTagLayout"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/mainLogo"
android:layout_width="25dp"
android:layout_height="25dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/profile" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the starting portion of my layout. The view was supposed to take up only 1/20th height of my screen. But it is taking almost 80% of the screen. I cannot figure out what I have done wrong. Can someone please point out

Comment: Please share full layout

Comment: @LaurentY Please check now. I have shared the full layout

Comment: Which view are you talking about? Also your weightSum equals the sum of all layout_weight entries, this achieves nothing. And you're still missing part of your layout.

Comment: You set some decimal values for Your views. If You do this, do it for all views, not only for some. Or You have to set int values for all views..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use same "type" (int or float) for layout_weight. Try this only with int:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MasterLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="4000">
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="200"
    android:background="#ff0ff000"
    android:visibility="visible" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Name"
    android:text="James Madison"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#4b8dcf"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="300"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff0ff000" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1000"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/pro1" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Title"
    android:text="Lead Civil Engineer"
    android:textColor="#4b8dcf"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="150"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Company"
    android:text="Telco Corp"
    android:textColor="#4b8dcf"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="175"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Pitch"
    android:text="Engineer specializing in bridge construction and maintenance. Looking for mechanical engineers and designers to work on an exciting new project."
    android:textColor="#A7A9AB"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000" />
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/TagMasterLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="500">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TagLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/GreenTagMasterLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="500">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/GreenTagLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mainLogo"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="75"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Comment: Actually , in the layout preview, the output is as expected. But when the layout gets loaded in the device, it is wrong

Comment: @TinkuChacko, I try on a tablet and a phone and not reproduce. First component View (green) just take little space before name

Comment: @TinkuChacko, you only have 1 device to test ?

Comment: @LaurentY No. I have checked on two devices. It is the same on both the devices. I am inflating this layout in to a view that is populated with an adapter. May be something is wrong there.

Comment: I create an activity and use setContentView and there's no problem, please share adapter and parent layout

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one root element in your XML.

Everything should be wrapped around your initial `LinearLayout` "MasterLayout".

Comment: Maybe it's set programmatically ? I don't know. What's inside your view?